# How can I install mediapipe package into Pycharm and access the terminal?

Tags: python

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqftB.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ5v5.jpg)

I know I should go into the terminal and paste some code [like in the first image] but I don't know how to go to the jetbrains terminal.

I want to use this package to detect faces; I want to create a cursor that works by tracking eye movement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.